# Confluence: How to pass posting date while creating a blogpost?

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to migrate Wordpress blog post to Confluence blog space. I am using Confluence api to post the the blog. I also need to set the **posting date** somewhere in past(original posting date on Wordpress). Confluence Web-UI provides an option to customize the posting date, but I didn't see anything in the API documentation which can allow me to pass the posting date. Here is my python script which is able to create the blog post but without customizing the "posting date"

```
import requests
import json


def main():
    auth = open('/tmp/confluence', 'r').readline().strip()
    username = 'rakesh'
    base_url = "https://<HOSTNAME>/rest/api/content/"
    space_key = "LOC"

    html_body = """<h1>This is h1 header</h1>
                   <p> this is paragraph</p>
                   <table> <tr> <td> data block1</td> <td> data block2</td> </tr></table>"""
    data = {'type': 'blogpost',
            'title': 'Blog test4',
            'space': {'key': space_key},
            'body': {'storage': {'value': html_body,
                                 'representation': 'storage'}}}

    response = requests.post(base_url,
                             auth=(username, auth),
                             headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                             data=json.dumps(data))

    print response.status_code, response.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the request json:

```
{'type': 'blogpost',
                'title': 'Blog test4',
                'space': {'key': space_key},
                'body': {'storage': {'value': '<h1>This is h1 header</h1><p> this is paragraph</p>',
                                     'representation': 'storage'}
                        }
 }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? doing something similar

Comment: @PhillPafford I couldn't figure out this issue. I checked their api but did not see anything useful. I also file a support ticket with them but they didn't provide any response.

Comment: I did see this post https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-40283

Comment: @PhillPafford You can change the posting date using UI. But you can't do it using the API. That bug only deals about the UI. :(

Answer (score 2):

We just did the same thing. To pass the post date, you just need to add history.createdDate in your request json.

```
{
    'type': 'blogpost',
    'title': 'Blog test4',
    'space': {
        'key': space_key
    },
    'history': {
        'createdDate': '2016-10-10T04:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'body': {
        'storage': {
            'value': '<h1>This is h1 header</h1><p> this is paragraph</p>',
            'representation': 'storage'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @YuxiaoTan.  Is there way to change the author name as well?

Comment: There's no direct way to change the author name. I also did a little bit research, never found any positive answers on this. Please let me know if you figure it out.